# Freshly installed Manjaro linux doesn't show up wifi

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi-configuration, linux-kernel, manjaro

I just installed Manjaro on my dell latitude 7389. Wifi worked just fine right after I installed. but after I did a full upgrade with "pacman -Syu" wifi stopped working. ethernet and bluetooth both works just fine tho. I even tried downgrading the kernel to 5.4 from 5.9. But it still doesn't work. when I tried "ip link" there were no wifi interface either.

```
ip link:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
12: enp0s20f0u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether be:8d:39:26:0f:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net:
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0150]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I tried installing almost every driver for this device but nothing worked. Also I haven't anything blacklisted. is there a way to fix this?